# MS SQL insert if not exist with a result

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, exists

I want to use an SQL table like an .ini file

so :

```
 select answer from x where (y=z)  
 if exists 
  {
   return answer (from databse)
  }
else
 {   
   insert into x, (answer) where (y=z)  
   return answer (from default)
 }
```

Where answer is a default value, that *may* be changed by the query.

I would like to do this in one query if possible, I can do it in two, but I feel sure there is a more elegant method.

Comment: You could possible use the OUTPUT clause into a temporary table and select from that temporary table. Check the MSDN articles on the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: Why insert? Why not just keep getting the default if it's not there? How does behaviour change if you silently insert, other than in a bad way that you can't then change the default. I think your idea is terrible. Inserting should be manual and carefully considered, not magic

Comment: Because my users may wish the default to be 30, or 70, or "apples" the code to adjust the default is elsewhere.  My users may decide that they want more than one value to measure.  I don't know, I'm here, they are in the future.  ini files are magic, and work exactly in this way just open 'em up in notepad, and your'e giggling, but I don't know (I'm in the past remember) if I will have access to the future users file system.  There is no shame in not knowing the answer Bohemian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming table c has the currently configured value and table d contains the system defaults

both with fields key (unique constraint) and val

I can use a union query to look up values

```
select top 1 * from ( 
  select 'c' source, key, val from c
  union all 
  select 'd', key, val from d
) x
where key = 'something'
order by source
```

this will return the configured value if it exists or the default if it does not.  I kind of agree with @bohemian - not sure I see the point of the insert, if the default value is changed then the query will still work.

If you really want to do the insert maybe look at rolling out a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why your mixing DML with your select as mentioned by @Bohemian
but on select part you can do something like below

```
select
case 
when exists(select answer from x where y=z) then answer
else (select answer from default) as answer
end
```